# Outlook on Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

When adding or deleting attendees to an existing invite, the 'Send update to all or only added or deleted attendees' dialog box doesn't show up for me anymore. It's only been doing this for the past couple of days - I haven't changed my settings, I've repaired my office systems and it's still not showing up.

Please help!

Comment: What does show?  Are you the meeting's Organizer?  Only the meeting's Organizer will get those options.

Comment: Nothing shows, I press 'Send' and the invite disappears where usually I am prompted first. And yes, I am the organiser

Comment: Are the Attendees listed by their names, and is there a Distribution List that was invited as an attendee?  If there is a Distribution List that is invited to the meeting, when updating the attendee list (add/remove), the "Send updates only to added or deleted attendees" prompt will not be displayed.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2732379/outlook-does-not-prompt-the-meeting-organizer-to-send-updates-only-to

Comment: Thank you, there is no distribution list. I have only added each attendee individually via the 'Address Book'. I've done this for years and for years have been prompted before the invite sends again but for the past week it has stopped doing it. Can't find anything in the settings which indicates the change

Comment: It's doing this with every invite I create